# Adding EXIF DateTime to a jpeg image

Tags: c#, bitmap, jpeg, exif

Problem:

**WebEye.WebCameraControl** makes an excellent job to capture a picture (Bitmap) in a WinForm App.
When saving the image (Bitmap): **image.Save("filename.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)** it will not add any
**exif** data, my need is just datetime.
There are many exampels how to read PropertyItems from an existing jpg, change attributes and save the image. But I cannot find any that adds new propertyItems to an "exif-empty" image.

There is **image.SetPropertyItem(propItem)** that looks promising but the **propItem** it self cannot be instantiated but retrieved from an image **image.PropertyItems[x]** Yes, I do miss something here but what?

Please save my day. This issue is driving me nutts.

Best regards
Stephan

Comment: First check: Are you sure it is creating EXIF files and not some other JPEG format?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, not at all. I am using the
image.Save("filename.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg) (.Net Bitmap method)
If it can be saved as EXIF-JPEG it will probably solve the problem. My problem is that I just have dived into the EXIF business.

Comment: There are a number of JPEG file formats. If it is Exif then it is always possible to write your own data to the exif tags. If not exif, you will need to do something else.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have no idea how to mix Jpeg and Exif.
image.Save("filename.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg | ImageFormat.Exif) would be excellent :-)